# Blender 3.3.0 Python access to selected nodes in the shader editor

Tags: python, scripting, shader-nodes

I would like to create a simple script that will change the values in selected "Value" nodes, but I cannot find information on how to access the list of selected nodes in the active material.
I thought something like this would work, but I was wrong:

`sel = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active`

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix it, so thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just go through nodes and check if they are selected and if the type matches the one you need:

```
import bpy

nodes = bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes

for n in nodes:
    if n.select and n.type=="VALUE":
        n.outputs['Value'].default_value = 15
```

You can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the Python console panel to use autocomplete function and find a lot of stuff about Blender's Python API:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you very much :)