# How do I find the output names on Nodes for Python in Blender 4?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, shader-nodes

After many frustrating days I've managed to get my bake script to not crash, and now I'm banging my head against a wall to have it work with the new BSDF shaders.

I knew the inputs were different, but one thing I did not expect is that the Color Mix node I now have to feed the Diffuse and Subsurface into would give me trouble.

```
>>> mix = bpy.data.materials["Fingernails"].node_tree.nodes["DS_Mix"]
>>> for i, o in enumerate(mix.outputs):
...     1, o.name
...     i, o.name
...     
(1, 'Result')
(0, 'Result')
(1, 'Result')
(1, 'Result')
(1, 'Result')
(2, 'Result')
(1, 'Result')
(3, 'Result')
```

The node itself only has one output you can interact with, so how does it have all these hidden ones? And how am I supposed to cal these in Python to make links?

`mat.node_tree.links.new(ds_mix.outputs[2], baked_BSDF.inputs[0])`
worked yesterday, but now it's not.

**Update**

I've made some progress after scouring around and finding the following pages:

- [Lookup nodes by output name](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/e4ad58114b9d56fe838396a97fe09aff32c79c6a)
- [Someone who's had a similar problem](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/113106)
- [An incomplete explanation of how they're now handled](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/104126)

And I now have a thing that makes the intended link:

```
tree = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree
#other defs
baked_BSDF = bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["Baked_BSDF"]
ds_mix = bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["Diff_Sub_Mix"]
#other stuff going on
def get_socket(sockets, identifier):
                for socket in sockets:
                    if socket.identifier == identifier:
                        return socket
tree.links.new(get_socket(ds_mix.outputs, 'Result_Color'), baked_BSDF.inputs['Base Color'])
```

So while this will probably work for most of what I'm currently tryign to do, I may come across some other node outputs that I'm not going to know the names of, and I can't just spend days guessing at each one.

So does anybody know how I can call the actual names up so I can put them in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

From [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/279298/149985) and some experimenting I discovered how to do this in the python console.

```
>>> mix = bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["Diff_Sub_Mix"]
>>> for i, o in enumerate(mix.outputs):
...     i, o.identifier
...     
(0, 'Result_Float')
(1, 'Result_Vector')
(2, 'Result_Color')
(3, 'Result_Rotation')

>>>
```

Should also work for the inputs, and the other fields and values of the nodes, *if you can find them*. I really wish the blender devs would actually include this kind of information in the docs.

Comment: inputs and outputs are dictionaries that you can access by name or index: outputs['name'] or outputs[0]. You can also outputs.get('name') to check if it exists.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of that? I'm always keen on more efficient ways to do things like that. If it works I'll update the answer to include it.

Comment: I don't know where to paste it as text for you, but here you are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSuAv.png

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. That's interesting but I was hoping you had a more efficient way of finding the names to *then* use in the script.

Comment: Either you already know the names (or indices) and just 'sockets[name]'... or what else?

Comment: It's a tedious process to find the names for **every** node. Lucky I won't need to do it for every node in my system, but I do need to have the script make several connections at strategic points in the baking process. I miss the old way where they were numbered from 0 and you could just count them.

Comment: but you can use indices... (as I told you)

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean. Maybe write a full answer to the question rather than turning this into a thread.

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: This is part of the process of updating my addon from 2.93 to 4.

Comment: ok, if I don't answer, this is because the question is not clear on some aspects: what is not working? why do you try to plug a material difrectly into a node tree?

Comment: The baking script has to switch between source nodes and output nodes for different textures, as well as ensure that the important connections exist when the process is finished.

Comment: Is the active material (first line where you get 'tree') the same as "Skin" material?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151914/discussion-between-misterlblends-and-lemon).